# Can i record a video based on a book and then publish it in Youtube?

Tags: copyright, germany

I have an idea to record **videos** based on some **books** and **then publish the videos in my channel in Youtube.**

**Of course, i will write a clear reference to the book and the author.**

But, i am wondering, if i am allowed to do so or not?

Here is a copyright rule of a target book:

> All rights reserved. No part of this publication may be reproduced or
>   transmitted in any form or by any means, electronic or mechanical,
>   including photocopy, recording, or any information storage and
>   retrieval system, without permission in writing from the publisher.

So, my question is, is it legal to build a youtube channel based on other people books?

Comment: “All rights reserved” is the *default* copyright status of every creative work. But could you explain a bit more how you would “base” the videos on the books? E.g. reading a complete book to the viewers would not be allowed, whereas discussing and analysing a book would likely be fine.

Comment: @amon No, i am going to explain what i understood from the book. Also, i might present some pictures or graphs of the book into my video.

Comment: Explaining something is not copying.